# How and where to define a custom jinja2 test

Tags: filter, flask, jinja2

I know this is obvious to everybody but me.

But where and how do I define a custom jinja2 test?

I tried specifying in my flask:

```
import flask
import jinja2
from jinja2 import environment as env
from jinja2 import *

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app = Flask(__name__)

# jinja2 filter
def isList(value):
  return isinstance(value, list)
env.tests['isList'] = isList
```

The resulting error is:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tests'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The configured Jinja2 environment for Flask applications is `app.jinja_env`. If you change the last line in your code to

```
app.jinja_env.tests['isList'] = isList
```

it should work properly.